# Call bash script from python and return variable

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I am trying to run the following code in Python which calls a Bash script file and saves its output to a variable. I am trying to use `subprocess.check_output` but it raises an error to the effect of "No such file or directory".  `subprocess.call` does not work either. Here is a bit of my code.

```
answer = subprocess.check_output(['/directory/bashfile.bash -c /directory/file -i input -o output'])
print answer
```

`-c` `-i` and `-o` are just arguments to the script `bashfile`.

Comment: can you explain exactly what "does not work". what happens when you run your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the entire command string rather than splitting them into args. You either need to pass it as a shell command:

```
answer = subprocess.check_output('/directory/bashfile.bash -c /directory/file -i input -o output', 
                                 shell=True)
print answer
```

Or you need to tokenize it yourself:

```
answer = subprocess.check_output(['/directory/bashfile.bash', 
                                  '-c', '/directory/file',
                                  '-i', 'input',
                                  '-o', 'output'])
print answer
```

For more information about subprocess refer to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) (python 3 version [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html))! Specifically you will want to read the section about ["Frequently used arguments"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)